# Navigating to directory in ZSH (bash)

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using [Oh-My-ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) to create some ailises and functions for easing my repetitive work load.

I need to navigate from anywhere in my computer to my Frontend directory. This is what I have:

```
frontend(){
  cd ~/Desktop/Work/Frontend
  cd $1
}
```

Now this works well when I type `frontend` or `frontend myProject`, however, all my project folders are postfixed by something like `.m`, `.tablet`, etc.

How can I write things that:

- Will let me automatically navigate to a folder that is followed by `.something`
- When there are multiple options (like `project.m` and `project.tablet`) will prompt me with options similar to if you hit tab in your terminal and are given multiple options for autocomplete.

I hope my question makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also give the `ls` output of the folder you are talking about which has .m & .tablet names?

Comment: @brokenfoot Possibly. I think I can do an `if` that will `ls` things when it fails, but how to keep it open for the user to choose which file eludes me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find a `zsh` solution first, followed by a `bash` solution.

**Update**: Turns out that a `zsh` implementation (based on builtin `compctl`) is much simpler than the `bash` implementation (based on builtin `complete`).

Save the code of interest to a file (e.g., `frontend`) and *source* it (e.g., `. ./frontend`); either interactively or, preferably, from your bash/zsh profile.

Once in place, auto-completion of subdirectory names in `~/Desktop/Work/Frontend` will work as follows:

- Type, for instance, `frontend  myProject` and press TAB.
- `myProject` is then prefix-matched against the names of the subdirectories in `~/Desktop/Work/Frontend`:

  - If there's only 1 match, `myProject` will instantly expand to the full subdirectory name.
  - Otherwise, a beep sounds to indicate that there are multiple matches:

    - `zsh`: The names of all matching subdirectories are listed right away.
    - `bash`: Press TAB *again* to list the names of all matching subdirectories
    - Continue typing until the prefix match is unambiguous, then press TAB again.

Note: In `bash`, to also only require pressing TAB *once* to list multiple matches, add the following to your shell profile `bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"`.

---

**zsh** solution:

```
# Define the shell function.
frontend(){
  cd ~/Desktop/Work/Frontend/"${1:-}"
}

# Tell zsh to autocomplete directory names in the same directory as
# the function's when typing a command based on the shell function.
compctl -/ -W ~/Desktop/Work/Frontend frontend
```

---

**bash** solution:

Note: `complete -o dirnames` doesn't take an argument, unfortunately - it always auto-completes for the *current* directory. Thus, a custom shell function that returns the potential matches, combined with `-o filenames`, is required.

```
# Define the main shell function.
frontend(){
    local BASEDIR=~/Desktop/Work/Frontend
  cd "$BASEDIR/${1:-}"
}

# Define the custom completion function.
_frontend_completions() {
    local BASEDIR=~/Desktop/Work/Frontend

    # Initialize the array variable through which
    # completions must be passed out.
  COMPREPLY=() 

    # Find all matching directories in the base folder that start
    # with the name prefix typed so far and return them.
  for f in "$BASEDIR/${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"*; do
    [[ -d $f ]] && COMPREPLY+=( "$(basename "$f")" )
  done

}

# Tell bash to autocomplete directory names as returned by the
# _frontend_completions() helper functoin when typing a command 
# based on the main shell function.
complete -o filenames -F _frontend_completions frontend fe
```

Comment: This sir, absolutely makes my day

Comment: @JDillon522 :) Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you use [AutoJump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump)

But if you must, maybe you want to use `alias`
like in your `~/.zshrc` add:

```
alias fend='cd path/to/frontend'
```

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. However, I work on multiple projects and it gets a bit repetitive creating aliases for each one. Granted, its 5 seconds out of my day. But my goal is to create something a bit more complex and flexible. Thanks though.

Comment: why don't you try `autojump` it is amazing, over time it learns where you cd to and you can say `j mydir` and it cd s you there from any where